# Button styles for different api versions?

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm working on an app that still targets down to API level 9.

I've added some buttons which show an image and some text - these are created using a RelativeLayout to avoid problems with image scaling, but they appear in light gray with white text because I was using the Widget.Button style. 
I tried setting Widget.Holo.Button, but then of course got a compilation error saying I need to target at least API v11.

So a bit more googling, and I worked out I can create a values-v11 folder as well as values.

So now, I have this in the values folder:

```
<resources>
    <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this in values-v11:

```
<resources>
    <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And I set my button to use the "ButtonStyle" style.

All well and good- no compilation errors. But now the buttons don't have any styling at all :(
I added a v21 folder and specified the Material button style in there, and that behaves the same way.

Can anyone point me to how to achieve what I want? (I have found plenty of stuff about completely custom styles but I don't really need that, I just want to be able to use the latest system style).

Answer (score 0):

And of course I figure it out right after asking.

I needed to change the parent value to the button style too, and now it seems to do what I hope...

(But shout if that's still wrong!)